# Alarma se dispara de inmediato en lugar de la hora programada en jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-studio, jetpack-compose

Estoy intentando hacer que una alarma se programe de acuerdo a los datos recibidos de un DatePicker y un TimePicker en JetPack Compose, este el código actual:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    lateinit var navController: NavHostController
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            navController = rememberNavController()
            NotePadReminderTheme {
                SetupNavGraph(navController = navController)
            }
        }
    }
}


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
fun createAlarm(context: Context,time:Long){
    val alarmManager =context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as? AlarmManager
    val intent =Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
    Log.d("receivedtime","time $time")
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, Date().seconds, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    alarmManager?.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent)
    Toast.makeText(context,"Alarma creada",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Composable
fun AddPage(navController: NavController, vm: TaskViewModel = viewModel()) {
    val scope= rememberCoroutineScope()
    val title = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val description = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val date = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val time = Calendar.getInstance()

    val iscompleted = remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 30.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Agregar Tarea",
            style = NoteTheme.typography.h1
        )

        RowOfThis(title, "Título", true)
        RowOfThis(description, "Descripción", false)
        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            DatePick(date)
        }
        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            TimePick(time)
        }

        Button(
            onClick = {
                if (title.value.isNullOrBlank() || description.value.isNullOrBlank() ||
                    date.value.isNullOrBlank()
                ) {
                    Log.d("date","date:${date.value}")
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Por favor ingrese todos los datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                    return@Button
                }
                vm.task.value.title = title.value
                vm.task.value.description = description.value
                vm.task.value.date = date.value
                vm.task.value.time = time.timeInMillis
                Log.d("tmepickerreceived","date:${time.timeInMillis}")
                scope.launch {
                    vm.createTask(context, vm.task.value)
                    createAlarm(context, time=time.timeInMillis). //here set the alarm ****************
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Tarea creada correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    vm.resetTask()
                }

            },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Blue)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Guardar", color = Color.White, style = NoteTheme.typography.subtitle)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RowOfThis(value: MutableState<String>, label: String, single: Boolean) {

    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(10.dp)
    ) {
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .border(BorderStroke(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Black)),
            singleLine = single,
            maxLines = 3,
            textStyle = NoteTheme.typography.body,
            value = value.value, onValueChange = {
                value.value = it
            }, label = {
                Text(
                    text = label, textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                    color = Color.DarkGray,
                    style = NoteTheme.typography.subtitle
                )
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(backgroundColor = Color.White),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onNext =
            { focusManager.moveFocus((FocusDirection.Next)) })
        )
    }
}


@Composable
fun DatePick(mDate:MutableState<String>) {
    val mContext = LocalContext.current

    val mYear: Int
    val mMonth: Int
    val mDay: Int

    val mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    mCalendar.time = Date()

    val mDatePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
        mContext,
        { _: DatePicker, mYear: Int, mMonth: Int, mDayOfMonth: Int ->
            mDate.value = "$mDayOfMonth/${mMonth + 1}/$mYear"
        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay
    )
    mDatePickerDialog.datePicker.minDate=Date().time
    Log.d("datepicker","dateset:${mDate.value}")
    Button(modifier = Modifier
        .padding(7.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth(0.5f), onClick = {
        mDatePickerDialog.show()
    }, colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color(0XFF227093))) {
        Text(text = "Seleccionar fecha",
            color = Color.White, style = NoteTheme.typography.subtitle)
    }
    Text(text = "${mDate.value}",style = NoteTheme.typography.caption, fontSize = 22.sp, color = Color(0XFF227093))
}



@Composable
fun TimePick(mCalendar:Calendar) {
    val mContext = LocalContext.current


    val mHour = mCalendar[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY]
    val mMinute = mCalendar[Calendar.MINUTE]

    val mTime = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    val mTimePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(
        mContext,
        {_, mHour : Int, mMinute: Int ->
            mTime.value = "$mHour:$mMinute"
        }, mHour, mMinute, false
    )

    Log.d("tmepicker","time:${mCalendar.timeInMillis}")
    Button(modifier = Modifier
        .padding(7.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth(0.5f), onClick = {
        mTimePickerDialog.show()
    }, colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color(0XFF2c2c54))) {
        Text(text = "Seleccionar hora",
            color = Color.White, style = NoteTheme.typography.subtitle)
    }
    Text(text = "${mTime.value}",style = NoteTheme.typography.caption, fontSize = 22.sp, color = Color(0XFF2c2c54))
}
```

Sin embargo el problema que tengo es que cuando se configura la alarma , es decir cuando llamo al método setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() la alarma se ejecuta de una vez y no debería ser así sino a la hora y fecha de los datos enviados (time). Alguna idea de porque pasa esto ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto se debía a que por alguna razón cuando uno obtiene el mes del calendario hay que sumarle uno , no se porque entonces eso estaba causando una ambiguedad cuando se establecía la fecha para crear la alarma. Este es el código final :

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val context= LocalContext.current
            AlarmTestTheme {
                mainPage(context)
            }
        }
    }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Composable
fun mainPage(context: Context) {
    val scope= rememberCoroutineScope()
    val calendar=Calendar.getInstance().apply {
        timeInMillis=System.currentTimeMillis()
    }

    val title = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val description = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val year= remember {
        mutableStateOf(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR))
    }

    val month= remember {
        mutableStateOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)
    }

    val day= remember {
        mutableStateOf(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
    }

    val hour= remember {
        mutableStateOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))
    }

    val minutes= remember {
        mutableStateOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
    }

    val iscompleted = remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 30.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Agregar Tarea"
        )

        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            DatePick(context = context, year = year, month = month, day = day)
        }
        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            TimePick(context = context, hours = hour, minutes = minutes)
        }

        Button(
            onClick = {

                Log.d("tmepickerreceived","date and time  :${year.value}/${month.value}/${day.value} : ${hour.value}:${minutes.value}")
                calendar.apply {
                    set(Calendar.YEAR,year.value)
                    set(Calendar.MONTH,(month.value-1))
                    set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day.value)
                    set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour.value)
                    set(Calendar.MINUTE,minutes.value)
                }


                val alarmMgr= context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

                val shuff=(1..99999).shuffled().first()

                val intent= Intent(context,AlarmReceiver::class.java)
                intent.action="alarma"
                intent.putExtra("ALARMA_STRING","alarm number: $shuff")
                val pending=
                    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,shuff,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

                Log.e("time final","compare ${System.currentTimeMillis()}" +
                        " mytime: ${calendar.timeInMillis} " +
                        "hour: ${calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)} " +
                        "minute: ${calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)} " +
                        "year: ${calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)} " +
                        "month: ${calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1} " +
                        "day: ${calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)}")

                alarmMgr?.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.timeInMillis,pending)

                Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()

            },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Blue)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Guardar", color = Color.White)
        }
    }
}



@Composable
fun DatePick(context: Context, year: MutableState<Int>,month: MutableState<Int>,day: MutableState<Int>) {

    val mDatePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
        context,{d,mYear,mMonth,mDay ->
            year.value=mYear
            month.value=mMonth+1
            day.value=mDay
        }, year.value, month.value, day.value
    )

    mDatePickerDialog.datePicker.minDate=System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000

    Log.d("datepicker","${day.value}/${month.value}/${year.value}")
    Button(modifier = Modifier
        .padding(7.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth(0.5f), onClick = {
        mDatePickerDialog.show()
    }, colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color(0XFF227093))) {
        Text(text = "Seleccionar fecha",
            color = Color.White)
    }
    Text(text = "${day.value}/${month.value}/${year.value}", fontSize = 22.sp, color = Color(0XFF227093))
}



@Composable
fun TimePick(context: Context,hours:MutableState<Int>,minutes:MutableState<Int>) {

    val mTimePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(
        context,
        {_, mHour : Int, mMinute: Int ->
            hours.value=mHour
            minutes.value=mMinute
        }, hours.value, minutes.value, false
    )

    Log.d("tmepicker","hour selected :${hours.value}: munute selected: ${minutes.value}")
    Button(modifier = Modifier
        .padding(7.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth(0.5f), onClick = {
        mTimePickerDialog.show()
    }, colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color(0XFF2c2c54))) {
        Text(text = "Seleccionar hora",
            color = Color.White)
    }
    Text(text = "${hours.value}:${minutes.value}", fontSize = 22.sp, color = Color(0XFF2c2c54))

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás definiendo tu alarma de esta forma,

```
mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
```

en realidad obtendrías el mes anterior, ya que esto es lo que indica la constante [MONTH](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar#MONTH) de la clase [Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar#MONTH) indica:

> [Calendar.MONTH](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar#MONTH) Este es un valor específico del calendario. El
> primer mes del año en los calendarios gregoriano y juliano es `ENERO`
> que es 0; el último depende del número de meses en un año.

Por lo tanto, siendo el día 28 de septiembre (mes 9) del 2022, debes sumar 1 a `mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)` para obtener el mes correcto:

```
val mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
val mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
val mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1
val mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)    
println("$mDay $mMonth $mYear")
```

Salida:

```
28 9 2022
```